# How can I combine these two VBA formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA macro for Excel that essentially hardcodes all values and formulas, comments, and images; deletes hidden columns and rows; deletes everything outside of the print range; and deletes any sheets named 'Input' or 'Inputs'.

I have been attempting to include code to also deleted grouped rows and columns, but cannot seem to get the code to execute when all contained in one macro, it simply runs without completing any of the functions - I've separated the grouped data deletion and hardcode codes into separate files as a temporary solution. What I am doing wrong here?

HARDCODE FORMULA

```
Sub Hardcode()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim tCmt As CommentThreaded
    Dim numCol As Long, numRow As Long
    Dim lc As Long, lr As Long
    Dim PrintRange As Range, RepeatRows As Range

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' Check if repeated rows are within print range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set PrintRange = Ws.Range(Ws.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        Set RepeatRows = Ws.Rows(Ws.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not PrintRange Is Nothing And Not RepeatRows Is Nothing Then
            Dim newStartRow As Long
            Dim newEndRow As Long

            newStartRow = PrintRange.Row
            newEndRow = PrintRange.Rows(PrintRange.Rows.Count).Row

            ' Check if repeated rows are above print range
            If RepeatRows.Row < PrintRange.Row Then
                newStartRow = RepeatRows.Row
            End If

            ' Check if repeated rows are below print range
            If RepeatRows.Row + RepeatRows.Rows.Count - 1 > newEndRow Then
                newEndRow = RepeatRows.Row + RepeatRows.Rows.Count - 1
            End If

            ' Adjust the print range to include header rows
            If newStartRow <> PrintRange.Row Or newEndRow <> PrintRange.Rows(PrintRange.Rows.Count).Row Then
                Ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(newStartRow, PrintRange.Column), _
                                                  Ws.Cells(newEndRow, PrintRange.Columns(PrintRange.Columns.Count).Column)).Address
                Set PrintRange = Ws.Range(Ws.PageSetup.PrintArea) ' Update the PrintRange variable
            End If
        End If

        ' Delete data outside of print range
        If Not PrintRange Is Nothing Then
            ' Delete data above print range
            If PrintRange.Row > 1 Then
                Ws.Range("1:" & PrintRange.Row - 1).Delete
            End If

            ' Delete data below print range
            If PrintRange.Rows(PrintRange.Rows.Count).Row < Ws.Rows.Count Then
                Ws.Range(PrintRange.Rows(PrintRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1 & ":" & Ws.Rows.Count).Delete
            End If

            ' Delete data to left of print range
            If PrintRange.Column > 1 Then
                Ws.Range(Ws.Columns(1), Ws.Columns(PrintRange.Column - 1)).Delete
            End If

            ' Delete data to right of print range
            If PrintRange.Columns(PrintRange.Columns.Count).Column < Ws.Columns.Count Then
                Ws.Range(Ws.Columns(PrintRange.Columns(PrintRange.Columns.Count).Column + 1), Ws.Columns(Ws.Columns.Count)).Delete
            End If
        End If

        ' Hardcode values
        On Error Resume Next
        Ws.UsedRange.Copy
        Ws.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling

        ' Delete comments for Excel 2011-2019
        For Each cmt In Ws.Comments
            cmt.Delete
        Next cmt

        ' Delete threaded comments for Excel 2021+
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each tCmt In Ws.CommentsThreaded
            tCmt.Delete
        Next tCmt
        On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete all images
    For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp

        ' Delete hidden columns
        lc = Ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For numCol = lc To 1 Step -1
            If Ws.Columns(numCol).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
                Ws.Columns(numCol).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next numCol

        ' Delete hidden rows
        lr = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For numRow = lr To 1 Step -1
            If Ws.Rows(numRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                Ws.Rows(numRow).Delete
            End If
        Next numRow

        ' Convert font to black for the current worksheet
        ConvertFontToBlack Ws

    Next Ws

    ' Delete sheets named "Inputs"
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = "Inputs" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next Ws

    ' Delete sheets named "Input"
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name = "Input" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next Ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub

Sub ConvertFontToBlack(ByRef Ws As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Ws.UsedRange.Cells
        If cell.Font.ColorIndex <> 2 Then
            cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End If
        
    Next cell
End Sub
```

GROUPED DELETION FORMULA

```
Sub DeleteGroups()
Dim RngToDelete As Range
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  Set RngToDelete = Nothing
  For Each colm In Sht.UsedRange.Columns
    If colm.OutlineLevel > 1 Then
      If RngToDelete Is Nothing Then Set RngToDelete = colm Else Set RngToDelete = Union(RngToDelete, colm)
    End If
  Next colm
  If Not RngToDelete Is Nothing Then RngToDelete.EntireColumn.Delete

  Set RngToDelete = Nothing
  For Each rw In Sht.UsedRange.Rows
    If rw.OutlineLevel > 1 Then
      If RngToDelete Is Nothing Then Set RngToDelete = rw Else Set RngToDelete = Union(RngToDelete, rw)
    End If
  Next rw
  If Not RngToDelete Is Nothing Then RngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
Next Sht
End Sub
```

Comment: "cannot seem to get the code to work when all contained in one macro" - specifically what does it do *instead* of work when you combine these?  We can't really guess.

Comment: @TimWilliams apologies, this is my first time using Stack Overflow - when I run the combined macro, I don't get an error message. Excel simply hangs for a second or two then life continues as though the code executed properly.

Comment: Can you show how you combined them?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to find out what is happening?